# divide one pandas series by another and ignore the indices

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas series. Series a has 20 values and has an index that starts from 0.

Series b also has 20 values but the index starts from 3.

So when I divide series a by b the first 3 numbers or nan I believe this is because of the different indices.

How do I get python to ignore the index I just want the 20 numbers in series a divided by the corresponding 20 numbers in series b?

Comment: `a.values / b.values` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of output index values, so divide by numpy array from `Series`:

```
a = pd.Series([2,5,3])
b = pd.Series([8,2,1]).rename(lambda x: x + 3)


s1 = a / b.values
```

Or create default index values by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
s1 = a / b.reset_index(drop=True)

print (s1)
0    0.25
1    2.50
2    3.00
dtype: float64

s2 = a.values / b
print (s2)
3    0.25
4    2.50
5    3.00
dtype: float64
```